# Eclipse Editor consumes AltGr+A even after disabling keyboard shortcut

Tags: eclipse, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Eclipse and a non-QWERTY keyboard. My @ sign is typed through <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. This is on Windows 7.

The Eclipse Editor won't let me type an @ which is bad.

I disabled the key shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, it still doesn't work.

@ works in other programs and in other windows inside Eclipse (e.G. find, options etc.) but not in Editor.

As this also applies to <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (which is my } ) a general solution as to how to figure out what key events get consumed would be nice.

Comment: Is this Mac OS X, Windows or Linux? There is code in the `StyledText` widget that the editor uses which ignores some inputs, what is ignored varies depending on the platform.

Comment: @greg-449 This is Windows 7, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: On Windows the widget ignores anything with just Alt or Ctrl or Alt+Shift or Ctrl+Shift. The code claims that Alt Gr should look like Ctrl+Alt and would get through. There is a very old Eclipse [bug 20953](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20953) which sounds like this problem, but it supposed to have been fixed long ago by the code I mentioned.

Comment: @grep-449 Thank you! That helped, after unbinding CTRL-Alt-A I'm able to type @! Would you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: OK, added slightly expanded answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse editors use the `StyledText` widget. This ignores some inputs depending on the platform.

On Windows the widget ignores anything with just Alt or Ctrl or Alt+Shift or Ctrl+Shift. The code claims that Alt Gr should look like Ctrl+Alt and would get through.

On Macs Cmd and Cmd+Shift is ignored.

On Linux / Motif Ctrl and Ctrl+Shift is ignored.

There is a very old Eclipse [bug 20953](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20953) which sounds like this problem, but it supposed to have been fixed long ago by the code I mentioned.

Comment: That info "Alt Gr should look like Ctrl+Alt" helped me most as then I could disable the hotkeys that used that combination and thus freeing my keys again.